# Behaviour of roots of a polynomial with function coefficients

Tags: analysis, polynomials, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

Let $(-1+c_4(h))x^4 +c_3(h)x^3+c_2(h)x^2+c_1(h)x+c_0(h)=0$ be an equation with variable coefficients, depending smoothly on $h$. Also let  $0\le c_4(h)\le 1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $c_0(h)>\epsilon'$  for some $\epsilon'>0$. One can easily see that for any $h$, this equation has two real solution, one positive and one negative. Let $z(h)$ be the positive roots. The question is that under what conditions I can say that $z(h)$ is a differentiable function of $h$?

Comment: The thing you can see easily is false. Consider the $c_i$ all constant such that your quartic becomes $-x^4-1$, which has no real solutions, or $-x^4+3x-1$, which has two, both positive.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, I have forgotten to mention a point on the coefficients which is edited now. Anyway, many thanks for your comments!

Comment: Apply the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, As you may have noticed implicit function theorem tag I have used. I had used it, the result depends on the roots of similar equation and just this. In fact, my question is there any straight forward condition or some nice special cases... that I can use here?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag :-(.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can have one or two positive roots. Using the IFT,
$$
0\ne\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-1+c_4(h))x^4+c_3(h)x^3+c_2(h)x^2+c_1(h)x+c_0(h)\Big\vert_{x=z(h)}
$$
$$
=4(-1+c_4(h))x^3+3c_3(h)x^2+2c_2(h)x+c_1(h)x\Big\vert_{x=z(h)}
$$
while
$$(-1+c_4(h))x^4 +c_3(h)x^3+c_2(h)x^2+c_1(h)x+c_0(h)\vert_{x=z(h)}=0,$$
i.e.,the root(s) $z(h)$ ($z_1(h)$, $z_2(h)$) is (are) simple.